# What is the matter with my file upload to php server in android?

Tags: php, android, eclipse

I am developing and application in eclipse, which uploads a simple txt file to a php server. My problem is that when I try to debug it, eclipse perspective changes and writes this: [image]

My code is:

```
    package com.example.tryyy;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    String url = "http://www.acliberation.comeze.com/upload.php";

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        "kutya.txt"); {

    try {
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
       InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
         new FileInputStream(file), -1);

    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");

    reqEntity.setChunked(true);

    // Send in multiple parts if needed

    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(),
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       // Do something with response...
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

     }
    }
```

my manifest is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tryyy"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tryyy.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

server side php is:

```
<?php
$target_path  = "./";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
 " has been uploaded";
} else{
 echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

I have downloaded the sources for SDK for API 19 and the problem still exists.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Did you try to set a debug point and click on continue to see if execution is halted at that point? This usually happens when an api or some code is accessed for which the source cannot be found (code using an external library).

Comment: Also, apart from the member variables, please move the HTTP client code into your onCreate().

Comment: I use many external libraries, I think 5-6, I am referencing to them in the java build path

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint in the code and keep pressing continue till it is reached.

Comment: I have gone through all the points and the problem occurs when I click resume at the final point. So all the breakpoints are marked with a tick, and the app shuts down afterwards.

Comment: During debugging, this sometimes happens if the AndroidVx.jar is missing. Try to add this jar. Use this link - http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/

Comment: Have you moved the HTTP code into the onCreate()?? Just move it first. I think I found the issue.

Comment: I have done it by removing one } from between the oncreate and the http, and put one more to the end. I've tried it, but still the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your code a little. Try it

```
package com.example.tryyy;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String url = "http://www.acliberation.comeze.com/upload.php";
    private String[] params;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        params = new String[2];
        params[0] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "kutya.txt";
        params[1] = url;
        new HTTPRequest().execute(params);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private class HTTPRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String returnString = null;
            try {
                File file = new File(params[0]);
                URI uri= new URI(params[1]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
                InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(file), -1);
                reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");    
                reqEntity.setChunked(true); 
                // Send in multiple parts if needed
                httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                returnString = response.toString();
                // Do something with response...
            } catch (Exception e) {
                returnString = e.getMessage();
            }
            return returnString;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it has no problems now, but the app says: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Right! I thought this might happen. It's because you are sending an http request inside an activity. Instead, try using a separate thread or an AsyncTask would actually be better.

Comment: I've added the AsyncTask. Try it. Do remember to import all required packages. I forgot to add that to the code.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to add the file path to the params. Wait a while.

Comment: Well I didn't change the original code. The toast displays the value of "response.toString()". That is what you had done.

Comment: so the problem should be with the server side?

Comment: Yes. I'm guessing you want a response from the server? Try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246068/http-post-on-android

Comment: I just want the server to store the txt i upload. Could you suggest me a code to do that? The one I use at the moment is not sure to work

Comment: Sorry buddy but I'm not familiar with php. Look around online. You should find something.