# Android web service, REST or KSOAP2 or get/post

Tags: android, web-services, rest, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

As of now, if I have to store something from Android to the server, I make an HTTP request of a `GET` URL, with data in the form of parameter values. On the server side, I use PHP to extract the parameter values and store them in database.

Similarly, if I want to get something from the server to Android, I post a JSON string on the webpage using PHP. Then I read it in Android using HTTP request, convert the string to JSON and then use the data.

This method of PHP-MySQL-Android-JSON is very easy but not secure. Suppose I want to store the score of player from my game in Android to the server's database, it is easy to execute some URL like `www.example.com/save_score.php?player_id=123&score=999` from Android. But anyone can update his score if he comes to know the php file name and names of parameters, by simply typing this URL in a browser.

So what is the correct method of interacting with a server (my server supports PHP but not Java)?

I have heard about RESTful and KSOAP2, but know nothing about them. Can you please explain them a bit in lay man language (reading the proper definitions didn't help me)? What are these used for?

What is the best way to send score to the server? Any tutorial link would be great.

Thanks.

**Edit 1**:
I don't use proguard to obfuscate my code for several reasons. So anyone can reverse engineer the apk, look into the code, find the URL to update the score, write his own POST method and update his score. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: I think you can read a lot about both on the interwebs and check out some examples. One advice though: SOAP is a real pain in the rear on Android, if you can chose go for REST period.

Answer (score 0):

Use POST method to post data from android and get it in php. e.g. use this method to send your data in json formate , which will not be showing in url.

```
    public static String sendRequest(String value, String urlString) {
        try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlString);
        httppost.setHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json");  
        //value = "";
        StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(value);
        stringEntity.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
        stringEntity.setContentType("application/json");
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, System.getProperty("http.agent"));

        httppost.setEntity(stringEntity); 

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String responseString = convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
        return responseString;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("check", ""+e.getMessage());
        return ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_RESPONDE;
        }
}
```

And call this method like this.

sendRequest({"player_id":1,"score":123}, "www.example.com/save_score.php");

And get json body in php and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read more documents about `RESTful`, Http `POST` and `GET` before starting. Your example url is GET method. It should be used for getting public information or query data. If you want to change something in server side, you should use `POST` method, it is more security than `GET`.
My recommend is using `RESTful` because it is painless than `SOAP`, especially for `Android`. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246068/http-post-on-android) is an example HTTP POST on Android.